# New to Paypal. Can't seem to find my paypal balance

Tags: paypal

I'm new to Paypal. I don't really understand how to use it yet. Why can't I seem to find my Paypal balance? I've been looking for it and I can't find it. I'Ve looked under Account Summary and Activity and it's not there. I created my PayPal account in 2017. I don't want to link my bank account to Paypal. Could someone please talk me through the process of finding it? Thanks

Comment: Have you ever moved money *to* Paypal, or only through it?  If you just used Paypal as an online checkout / digital wallet service, then you have no (or zero) Paypal balance, because the money pulled from debit or credit card was immediately paid out to the merchant's balance.

Comment: No I haven't. I want to use PayPal for online purchases

Answer (score 7):

For me (on the main website, not the mobile site) it shows up right there under "Summary", see the below screenshot. As you can see my balance is 0, because I don't keep money in there. You can still pay people using paypal even when there's no money in there, either using a credit card or a linked bank account (I know you said you don't want to do that but someone else who finds this question might be happy to).

[image]

On the mobile site I just go to paypal.com and log in, and then scroll down the page and it's a little way down the page, clearly headed "PayPal Balance".

Answer (score -5):

There's obviously no way to see your balance. My Summary web page doesn't show it. Paypal doesn't want you to know how much is there so you leave it for them to use interest free...

Comment: That's simply not true. They show your balance.